# Analytics - Build metrics for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, team-sites, web-analytics, site-usage

I would like build metrics for my time, I tried researching on this and found out that we can use the Popularity Trends in Site Settings Page, Unfortunately the analytics is broken for our farm and there is no way I can use the inbuilt trends and site usage statistics.

Would I be able to achieve in getting the site usage information, statistics and page hits information using any other means even if the Out of the Box analytics is broken.

Help is much needed

Answer (score 1):

What i believe, you need at least the ananlytics logs file inorder to get the report, you can run some querries against the usage database to get that data but again for SharePoint 2013 and higher you need following.

- Search service application is configured at the farm
- Usage and Data health data service application configured for analytics.

Here is the codeplex solution for this: [SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics Data Export to CSV using](https://sp2013wade.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#sp2013wade.ps1)

[Custom SQL views in the SharePoint logging database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715694(v=office.16).aspx#section3)